# azure function file function.json on a different location

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, azure-functions

While developing Azure functions, I started to get the error the function.json file couldn't be found on 
"C:...\FunctionApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin\function.json".

I realized the function.json file is generated but on a different location 
"C:...\FunctionApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Function1\function.json"

This started to happen long after I was developing azure functions with no trouble!

Any idea why this started to happen and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try to create a new azure function project and still have this error? What changes did you make that caused the problem?  Besides, try to delete bin and obj folder and then build again.

Comment: Besides, what is your vs version and your azure project type?

Comment: Hi even if bin and obj folders are deleted the result os the same. I created a new v2 function project and is the same. But if i create a v3 function project then ir works fine! I belive the older v2 projects should not have the problem othewise i am forced to spend a lot of time to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Actually**, the default azure function project will output the `function.json` on the `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Function1\function.json` folder as you said rather than `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin\function.json`.

**In my side**, the `function.json` will not appear under `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin\function.json` and I wonder why your project search on that location rather than the **Function1** folder. It is quite normal and I did not get the same issue on my Azure Function project. I wonder whether you have done any changes to your project.

**Suggestion**

**1)** close VS Instance, delete the `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder. Then, restart your project to test again.

**2)** try to create a new azure function project and then test whether it happens on the new project.

==============

If the new project also gets the same error, you should check whether you have installed any third party extensions that caused that situation

- disable any third party extensions under **Extensions** menu.
- [do a repair in Vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update VS to the latest version

If your new project did not get this error, the issue is related to your project itself. You should check every file carefully to prevent changes to `function.json` file and try **step 1**. Besides, you can also migrate your old project into the new project.

**In addition,** any feedback and detailed description about your issue will be expected and if I misunderstand your issue, it can help me locate the issue in the right direction.

Comment: I Will try your sugestios asap

Comment: it actually worked, deleting the .vs folder! thank you for the help Perry Qian!